# How to use tesseract to convert to PDF with multiple languages

Tags: pdf

I'm trying to ocr a pdf document in tesseract that has Greek and English text.

I converted the files to tiff since tesseract can't input pdf

```
tesseract file.tiff output -l eng+osd+ell
```

Gives me no errors, but it is in a text document I need it in PDF with the image of the document

So I use:

```
tesseract file.tiff output pdf -l eng+osd+ell
```

But I get the following error:

```
read params file: Can't open l  
read params file: Can't open eng+osd+ell
```

Tesseract is only allowing me to convert pdf in English only and keep the image but with text document it does English, osd, and Greek, but now I lose the picture contained in the pdf/tiff. How do I get it to convert to pdf with multiple languages?